# c# pattern for a visual interface to configure a service

Tags: c#, configuration, service

I have a service that runs in a privileged  mode but occasionally the user who is unprivileged will need to configure it (selecting relevant hardware etc). I need to provide a simple visual interface for this.

As services can't interact with the visual environment by creating windows etc, I'm wandering what the best way to provide this interface is. Are there any good methods or patterns that people have used in the past?

Cheers,

Richard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add a wcf self hosted service to your windows service.
publish in this service the method required, and create a client app to call this methods.

Answer (score 2):

I have used WCF to provide a very similar interface in the past. It has several advantages but all normal IPC are also available to you. If it is going to be on the same machine you can allow a service to interact with the desktop.

Comment: are you sure about this. The reading I've done http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/windowssdk/thread/f8f91e8f-5954-43a7-8bc4-80ed2ff1e3b1/ says this doens't work in Vista.

Comment: Yea I didn't realize that.  I guess I hadn't tried to go that route since xp so I never bumped up against it.